# How do I write a code for matrix using users input without numpy in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, matrix, floating-point

---Without using numpy---

I have to write a code where at i am receiving input from user, `n`, which is the number of rows of my matrix (integer). afterwards - I will be receiving from the user `n` rows of the matrix. and then I need to print the matrix, and the numbers should be floating numbers.  For example:

```
input :
2
12
34
output:
[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]
```

I started writing code.  I need help with converting the numbers from the string to floating numbers. This is the code I started. What do you recommend next?

```
n = int(input())
matrix= []

for i in range(n):
    row = []
    r = input()
    for j in range(n):
        row.append(r.split())
matrix.append(row)
print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have trouble with:

```
    row.append(r.split())
```

since `'12'.split()` is simply `['12']`.

OTOH `'1 2'.split()` will give `['1', '2']`, as would `list('12')`. Then you'll want FP values:

```
    row.append([float(digit) for digit in r])
```

Comment: Still error, it says it couldn’t convert string to float 

Comment: Well, if `r` is not exclusively digits, then `float(digit)` is going to have trouble. Consider testing `if digit.isnumeric()` to deal with invalid inputs. The example input you offered suggested there would be only digits. Maybe you want to `.rstrip()` to trim a trailing newline?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You just needed to append a new row twice. You did it only once. Indentation of the `matrix.append(row)` fixed the problem.

To make a numerical string character as a float number, you can use the build-in `float()` function. [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/float-in-python/)

```
n = int(input())
matrix= []

for i in range(n):
    row = []
    r = input()
    for j in range(n):
        row.append(float(r[j]))
    matrix.append(row)
print(matrix)
```

Comment: Hi it still doesn’t work, and the numbers are still a string and not floating

Comment: I fixed the issue. Every element "r[j]" just needs to be converted with a built-in function float()